# Do you include the endpoint/bounds when identifying an increasing/decreasing interval?

Tags: calculus

For example,  $y = x^2 +10x + 24$

On exactly what interval is this increasing ?

$y' = 2x + 10$

$2x + 10 = 0$

$x=-5$

<++++++++++++(-5)----------------->

So, is the function increasing on $x > -5$ or $x >= -5$ ?

$[-5,\infty)$   or    $(-5,\infty)$     ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=-5$ is minimum and on $x>-5$ the function increasing because for $f'(x>-5)$ the result is positive

therfore $\color{red}(-5,\infty)$

---

On $x<-5$ the function decreasing because for $f'(x<-5)$ the result is negative

therfore $(-\infty,-5\color{red})$

Comment: No, my question is specifically asking whether the endpoint of -5 is included or excluded from that interval.

Comment: @JackOfAll Nehorai's answer specifies that $-5$ is excluded; the $\gt$ and $\lt$ signs are used correctly. At $x = - 5$, the function is neither decreasing nor increasing.

Comment: the standard definition of increasing/decreasing is not what you used.

Comment: I've seen textbooks include the bounds in the interval.  Why such inconsistency?